# Binary diff/patch for large files on linux?

Tags: linux, diff, patch

I've got two partition images (A and B) and want to use them to create a patch that I can apply on A on another computer in order to get the new B image without flooding the network. I have the following requirements:

- works on Linux
- can create diffs
- can use diffs to patch files
- can handle binary files
- can handle large files (a few hundred GB should work)
- no user interaction required (just a console application)
- ideally, should be able to read from/write to pipes (so that I can pipe into it from a gzip-compressed file and write to one)

Does something like that exist?

Comment: I hit the Enter key too fast when starting the bounty. Here is the text I wanted to add:

Comment: *An answer with an easy-to-reproduce example for `rdiff` would be valuable for future reference. Example: Let's say `file1` and `file2` are two similar files of 1GB each. 1) How to compute the rdiff? 2) How to save this rdiff into a `patch` file? 3) How to apply this `patch` file to `file1` to recover `file2`?*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should probably take a look at the rsync-related tools: **rdiff** and **rdiff-backup**.
The `rdiff` command lets you produce a patch file and apply it to some other file.

The `rdiff-backup` command uses this approach to deal with entire directories, but I'm guessing you're working with single-file disk images, so `rdiff` will be the one to use.

Comment: What does "signature" and "delta" mean for rdiff? The man page doesn't say.

Comment: To answer my own question, creating a delta with rdiff is a two step process. First create a signature file from the old file, then use the signature and new file to create the delta. They can be run together with `rdiff signature oldfile | rdiff delta - newfile deltafile`

Comment: @TorKlingberg Could you post a new answer with a example? Let's say `file1` and `file2` are two similar files of 1GB each. 1) How to compute the diff? 2) How to save this diff into a patch file? 3) How to apply this patch file to `file1` to recover `file2`?

Answer (score 14):

[xdelta](http://xdelta.org/) can do everything you want.  Fair warning though, if your images aren't *very* similar, you can end up with a very large patch, because xdelta uses half of the defined memory buffer for finding differences.  More information is available at the [TuningMemoryBudget](https://code.google.com/p/xdelta/wiki/TuningMemoryBudget) wiki page.  Increasing the buffer size may help out quite a bit.

[bsdiff](http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/) is another option, but it's *very* RAM hungry and completely inappropriate for anything the size of a disk image.

> **bsdiff** is quite memory-hungry. It requires *`max(17*n,9*n+m)+O(1)`* bytes of memory, where *`n`* is the size of the old file and *`m`* is the size of the new file. **bspatch** requires *`n+m+O(1)`* bytes.

Comment: According to some reports (http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/old-list-archive/2002-February/000087.html) xdelta can produce much more efficient result (size-wise) than rdiff.

Answer (score 11):

## Canonical Answer

Regarding [rdiff](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rdiff) the post, [librsync 2.0.1](https://librsync.github.io/rdiff.html)
 is a good read for the command functionality clarification so I've referenced that below to preserve the content to this answer if nothing else.

It's important to try to get a good understanding of the rdiff [three steps to updating a file: **signature**, **delta**, and **patch**](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rdiff) as talked about on the [rdiff](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rdiff) man page. I've also found an `rdiff` command example script on GitHub that's helpful which I'll reference and quote.

> ### **Essentially...**
>
> 1. With a "starting" or base file [`file1`] and you create a **signature file** from it
>
>    - This is usually much smaller than the base/original file itself
> 2. With the **signature file** you compare it against another file [`file2`] similar to your base file but different (*e.g. recently
>      updated*) and create a **delta file** containing just the differences
>      between the two files
> 3. Use the "differences only" or **delta file** and compare it with your base file [`file1`] to generate a new file containing the changes
>      from the other file [`file2`] matching the two.

---

#### Quick Commands (per [`rdiff-example.sh`](https://gist.github.com/jpillora/edb83dc2d511c410cf46485e53569fdf))

```
rdiff signature file1 signature-file            ## signature base file1
rdiff delta signature-file file2 delta-file     ## delta differences file2
rdiff patch file1 delta-file gen-file           ## compare delta to file1 to create matching file2
```

---

> [**rdiff-example.sh**](https://gist.github.com/jpillora/edb83dc2d511c410cf46485e53569fdf)
>
> ```
> # $ rdiff --help
> # Usage: rdiff [OPTIONS] signature [BASIS [SIGNATURE]]
> #              [OPTIONS] delta SIGNATURE [NEWFILE [DELTA]]
> #              [OPTIONS] patch BASIS [DELTA [NEWFILE]]
>
> # Options:
> #   -v, --verbose             Trace internal processing
> #   -V, --version             Show program version
> #   -?, --help                Show this help message
> #   -s, --statistics          Show performance statistics
> # Delta-encoding options:
> #   -b, --block-size=BYTES    Signature block size
> #   -S, --sum-size=BYTES      Set signature strength
> #       --paranoia            Verify all rolling checksums
> # IO options:
> #   -I, --input-size=BYTES    Input buffer size
> #   -O, --output-size=BYTES   Output buffer size
>
> # create signature for old file
> rdiff signature old-file signature-file
> # create delta using signature file and new file
> rdiff delta signature-file new-file delta-file
> # generate new file using old file and delta
> rdiff patch old-file delta-file gen-file
> # test
> diff -s gen-file new-file
> # Files gen-file and new-file are identical
> ```

---

> ## [Introduction](https://librsync.github.io/rdiff.html)
>
> rdiff is a program to compute and apply network deltas. An rdiff delta
>   is a delta between binary files, describing how a basis (or old) file
>   can be automatically edited to produce a result (or new) file.
>
> Unlike most diff programs, librsync does not require access to both of
>   the files when the diff is computed. Computing a delta requires just a
>   short "signature" of the old file and the complete contents of the new
>   file. The signature contains checksums for blocks of the old file.
>   Using these checksums, rdiff finds matching blocks in the new file,
>   and then computes the delta.
>
> rdiff deltas are usually less compact and also slower to produce than
>   xdeltas or regular text diffs. If it is possible to have both the old
>   and new files present when computing the delta, xdelta will generally
>   produce a much smaller file. If the files being compared are plain
>   text, then GNU diff is usually a better choice, as the diffs can be
>   viewed by humans and applied as inexact matches.
>
> rdiff comes into its own when it is not convenient to have both files
>   present at the same time. One example of this is that the two files
>   are on separate machines, and you want to transfer only the
>   differences. Another example is when one of the files has been moved
>   to archive or backup media, leaving only its signature.
>
> **Symbolically**
>
> ```
> signature(basis-file) -> sig-file
>
> delta(sig-file, new-file) -> delta-file
>
> patch(basis-file, delta-file) -> recreated-file
> ```
>
> ---
>
> #### Use patterns
>
> A typical application of the rsync algorithm is to transfer a file A2
>   from a machine A to a machine B which has a similar file A1. This can
>   be done as follows:
>
> 1. B generates the rdiff signature of A1. Call this S1. B sends the signature to A. (The signature is usually much smaller than the file
>      it describes.)
> 2. A computes the rdiff delta between S1 and A2. Call this delta D. A sends the delta to B.
> 3. B applies the delta to recreate A2. In cases where A1 and A2 contain runs of identical bytes, rdiff should give a significant space
>      saving.
>
> [source](https://librsync.github.io/rdiff.html)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

[JDIFF](http://jojodiff.sourceforge.net/) is a program that outputs the differences between two (binary) files.